# Changing original vector does not change it in a collection

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Why do I get different output? How can I fix this? I want the trainingVector[0] to reference A.

```
vector<double> A(4,0);
vector<vector<double > > trainingVector;
A[0]=1;
trainingVector.push_back(A); 
A[0]=2;
cout << A[0] << endl ;
cout << trainingVector[0][0] << endl ;
```

Comment: Please add a little more detail, including how you declare and assign your variables.

Comment: Okay, I included that. Now trying the answers below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store references in STD containers, so what you ask for is impossible. If you want `trainingVector` to store a *pointer* to `A`, that's entirely doable:

```
vector<double> A(4,0);
vector<vector<double>*> trainingVector;

A[0] = 1;
trainingVector.push_back(&A);
A[0] = 2;

// notice that you have to dereference trainingVector[0] to get to A
cout << (*trainingVector[0])[0] << endl; // prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store a pointer to `A` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A(1);
    A[0] = 1;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>*> trainingVector;
    trainingVector.push_back(&A);
    A[0] = 2;
    std::cout << A[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*trainingVector[0])[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want the syntax as specified in the question, you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class VecRef
{
private:
    std::vector<T> *m_v;

public:
    VecRef(std::vector<T>& v)
    :   m_v(&v)
    {}

    T& operator[](int i)
    {
        return (*m_v)[i];
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A(1);
    A[0] = 1;
    std::vector<VecRef<int>> trainingVector;
    trainingVector.push_back(A);
    A[0] = 2;
    std::cout << A[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << trainingVector[0][0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already changed the syntax, so the first solution worked for me! Sorry I cant accept two answers :(